# How do I display the value of a variable in the diagram layer?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Below is a simple code I am trying:

```
model FirstOrderExperiment
  Real x "State variable";
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-32, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-32, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Blocks.Interaction.Show.RealValue realValue annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {6, 4}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
   initial equation
    x = 2 "Used before simulation to compute initial values";
  equation
    der(x) = 1 - x "Drives value of x toward 1.0";
y=x;
  connect(y, realValue.numberPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-32, 10}, {-18.75, 10}, {-18.75, 4}, {-5.5, 4}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
end FirstOrderExperiment;
```

I want the value of `x` to be shown in the diagram view of this model.

I used a `Interfaces.RealOutput` block to create an output `y`, which I equated to value of `x`. I used a `Interaction.Show` block and connected this output `y` to the input port of this block. However the value of the `Show` block remains at 0.0 even though value of `x` changes over time.

Comment: Did you opened the diagram window in the Plot View? In the PlotView double click on the model again and then use the arrows to play the simulation on the diagram. See Variables Browser here: https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DynamicSelect annotation as part of a component's icon. Here is an example:

```
model DisplayValue
  Real T=300;

  annotation (Icon(graphics={Text(
      extent={{-86,52},{46,4}},
      textColor={28,108,200},
      textString= DynamicSelect("T", String(T,significantDigits=4)+" K"))}));

end DisplayValue;
```

It's implemented the same way inside the `Show` Block from MSL.